# Leaving out undef'ed keys from Perl-JSON-module-encoded output

Tags: json, perl, encoding, null, decoding

I am using the [Perl JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm) module to encode some nested Perl object and array references (obtained from decoding JSON input) into pretty-printed JSON output.

So far, so good. However, I have a key that I'd like to remove from my reference input:

```
if (defined $originalJSON->{'myObsoleteKey'}) {
    undef $originalJSON->{'myObsoleteKey'};
}
```

It looks like this gets rendered into a `null` JSON element in my output:

```
{
    ...
    "myObsoleteKey" : null, 
    ...
}
```

I'd prefer to filter this out entirely. I guess I could write an `awk` script or something similar to do this manually, but I'm hoping there's a cleaner way to do this within the Perl JSON module. Is this doable?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of setting the hash element to `undef` you should delete it altogether.

Use

```
delete $originalJSON->{myObsoleteKey}
```

There is no need to check first whether it exists: if there is no such element then nothing will happen.

Comment: This did not seem to work for me; the (obsolete) key remains in the JSON output.

Comment: Please show your revised code. Have you misspelled the key perhaps?

Comment: I think the check for key existence trips it up. If I remove that sanity check, then the key is removed. I'm wary of not checking if the key exists though, and this leaves me wondering why this works when I remove the sanity check.